# pip.config contains parsing errors

Tags: python, pip

Whenever i try to use "pip install pathlib" (or any package) I get the following error. The http address is correct, aswell as the host address. Can anyone find the parsing error ?

```
Configuration file could not be loaded.
File contains parsing errors: /home/myself/.config/pip/pip.conf
[line  2]: '\textra-index-url = http://myaddress:8000\n'
[line  3]: '\ttrusted-host = myaddress\n'
```

Here is my configuration:

```
[global]
    extra-index-url = http://myaddress:8000
    trusted-host = myaddress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove tabs at the beginning of the lines. For [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) whitespaces at the beginning of a line means line continuation.

Comment: Worked a treat. Thank you!

Comment: I have the same error for my python2 environment when I try to use pip.  However, in my python3 environment,  my pip runs totally fine.   I removed tabs in the beginning, but it did not help.  Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: @Frank Did not help — means the same error? Perhaps there are more tabs? Other syntax errors?

Comment: @phd Thanks for your comment.  I ended up opening it using a different editor and save it, and it worked.